# Minimum buses required so that all passengers can reach stop 1

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

Given a city with `N` bus stop and `N-1` roads. All the city bus stops are reachable to each other via connecting roads. A stop can have value `0` or `1`. `0` represents that there is no passenger at this stop, and `1` represents that there are some passengers at this stop.

Find the minimum number of buses required so that all passengers can reach stop `1`.

A bus *cannot visit the same stop twice*, and each bus has *infinite capacity* .

[image: Example image]

My approach currently gets the number of leaf nodes which has encountered passengers at some point. However, my solution double counts in such a case as shown below:

Given these 2 possible paths: 1- 2 - 3 and 1- 2- 4, and given there there is only a passenger at node 2. My solution counts both paths as valid.

```
void dfs(int curr, int parent, bool passInPath, int *resPointer, unordered_map<int, vector<int> > &adjmap, int passengers[])
{
    bool leaf = true;
    bool passenger = false;
    if (passInPath || passengers[curr])
    {
        passenger = true;
    }
    for (auto neigh : adjmap[curr])
    {
        if (neigh != parent && neigh != 1)
        {
            dfs(neigh, curr, passenger, resPointer, adjmap, passengers);
            leaf = false;
        }
    }
    if (leaf && passenger)
    {
        *resPointer = *resPointer + 1;
    }
   
}

int minBuses(int N, int passengers[], int edges[][2])
{

    // first make adjacency list
    unordered_map<int, vector<int> > adjmap;
    for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
    {
        int e1 = edges[i][0];
        int e2 = edges[i][1];
        adjmap[e1].push_back(e2);
        adjmap[e2].push_back(e1);
    }

    // result pointer
    int res = 0;
    int *resP = &res;

    // start from node 1 and iterate through all its neighbouts and launch dfs
    for (auto neigh : adjmap[1])
    {
        dfs(neigh, 1, false, resP, adjmap, passengers);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: @nice_dev What Hamiltonian path? It's a tree.

Comment: @nice_dev A tree that has a Hamiltonian path is unary (each node has no more than 1 child). There is approximately zero work involved in finding such a path. It isn't quite clear how it helps solve this problem though.

Comment: A hamiltonian path in a tree, if it exists, is just the entire tree, the path from the root to the (only) leaf. What kind of utility are you planning to extract from it?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, an HM path may not be beneficial at all if a node has more than 1 kid. I assume we would need more than 1 bus for it. How many would be required for this tree? https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hRd8.png (The number against the node indicates no. of people boarding the bus from that node.).

Comment: If there is a node with more than 1 child, there are no hamiltonian paths. If there is no node with more than 1 child, there is one hamiltonian path and it's trivial. There is no utility in that whatsoever.  See my answer.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I think I already agreed that  hamiltonian paths are not useful here. Deleted my previous comments to avoid confusion for future readers.

Comment: @snowcoffeebean I think we would need some online link to test our perception. As I see it now, it seems that the answer is just 1 + extra kids that each node has where there are passengers.

Comment: @nice_dev sorry i dont have a link to test this..

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of one algorithm that could work:

```
procedure count_buses(node):
  sum = 0
  for child in node.children:
     sum += count_buses(child)
  sum = max (sum, node.has_passengers)
  return sum
```

Comment: Does `node.has_passengers` signify a boolean? If yes, we can't max it. We are counting buses for children here, so are we starting from node `1` or how is it?

Comment: @nice_dev "A stop can have value 0 or 1". It's that value. "are we starting from node 1" Yes, the top-level call should be count_buses(1).

Comment: It makes sense to me now, just like I anticipated after the HM confusion.